# How to push a new view upon opening push notification while app is closed?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, apple-push-notifications

So what I'm trying to do is when you click view on receiving a push notification when the app opens it has the presented view push a new controller with details regarding the notification. I'm using a UITabBarController with UINavigationControllers. Any help would be much appreciated, I've tried searching but I couldn't seem to find anything that pointed me in the right direction. Current code below:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];

[application setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque];

tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

controller = [[controller alloc] init];
UINavigationController *controller1 = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:controller] autorelease];
controller1.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_news.png"];
[controller setTitle:@"View"];
[controller release];

controller = [[controller alloc] init];
UINavigationController *controller2 = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:controller] autorelease];
controller2.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_news.png"];
[controller setTitle:@"View"];
[controller release];

controller = [[controller alloc] init];
UINavigationController *controller3 = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:controller3] autorelease];
controller3.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_news.png"];
[controller setTitle:@"View"];
[controller release];

controller = [[controller alloc] init];
UINavigationController *controller4 = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:controller] autorelease];
controller4.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_news.png"];
[controller setTitle:@"View"];
[controller release];

controller = [[controller alloc] init];
UINavigationController *controller5 = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:controller] autorelease];
controller5.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_news.png"];
[controller setTitle:@"View"];
[controller release];

tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:controller1, controller2, controller3, controller4, controller5, nil];

[window addSubview:tabBarController.view];

[window makeKeyAndVisible];

launchDefault = YES;
//[self performSelector:@selector(handlePostLaunch) withObject:nil afterDelay:0];

// Push Notification info

NSDictionary *apns = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];

NSString *result =  [[[apns valueForKey:@"aps"] valueForKey:@"alert"] valueForKey:@"loc-args"];

NSString *playerID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", result];

playerID = [[playerID componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]] componentsJoinedByString:@""];

playerID = [playerID stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"  " withString:@""];

playerID = [playerID stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"(" withString:@""];

playerID = [playerID stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@")" withString:@""];

NSLog(@"Player ID: %@", playerID);

if (![playerID isEqualToString:@"null"]) {
    if (!detailViewController) {
        detailViewController = [[PlayerDetailViewController alloc] init];
    }

    NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [[AppController sharedAppController] managedObjectContext];

    NSFetchRequest *req = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Players"
                                              inManagedObjectContext:moc];
    [req setEntity:entity];

    NSPredicate *pre = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"playerID=%@", playerID];
    [req setPredicate:pre];

    NSError *error;
    NSArray *list = [moc executeFetchRequest:req error:&error];

    [req release];

    Players *player = [list lastObject];

    [detailViewController setPlayer:player];

    //Want to Push view here

    [detailViewController release];

    detailViewController = nil;
}

return YES;
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If application is launched by a notification then it will be present in the application delegate's `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` launchOptions dictionary under the key UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey, which has all the info the notification has (JSON converted to NSDictionary I believe).

EDIT:

Got the question wrong, I think what you're looking for is just the pointer to the currently selected navigation controller. You get that if you query `[tabbarcontroller selectedViewController]`, which returns the visible navigation controller. Then simply push the newly created controller on top of the stack of that navigation controller.

Comment: I'm getting the notification information correctly, what I'm having issues with is automatically pushing the detail view within the app of the notification. Sorry if my question was worded poorly.

Comment: Edited my answer, my mistake, didn't quite get the question.

Comment: I've tried both [[[tabBarController selectedViewController] navigationController] pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES]; and [[tabBarController selectedViewController] presentModalViewController:detailViewController animated:YES]; but both of them end up with a SIGKILL in the int main() function. Am I wrong on how I should push the view on to the stack? I thought pushViewcontroller was what I was looking for.

Comment: The [tabBarController selectedViewController] is in this case a navigationController, no need to call navigationController on it. Just cast it into a temporary variable and push the detail controller onto there. UINavigationController *selectedNav = (UINavigationController *)[tabBarController selectedViewController]

Comment: That works great in the didReceiveRemoteNotification method for when the app is running in the background but for some reason in the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions I'm still getting SIGKILL. Is it even possible to do this on load of the app?

Comment: You could try to push the new view in the one of the methods of the navigation controllers eg viewDidAppear or something along those lines.

Comment: Well I got it to work. For whatever reason still running the app in xcode even after closing it on the device was causing the SIGKILL.